# Importing items to core data via CSV importer terminates the app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

if I save items from a add view, then this works. So I thought, that if I am in the same context and I use also the same data controller and method for storing items, then there won't be an issue.

However, if I do import my items via this CSVImporter class, then the following error occurs:

```
CoreData: error: +[Item entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'Item' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1996be69c 0x19194bc80 0x1a17ecf80 0x10297056c 0x102970600 0x1a18397dc 0x102942578 0x102941e00 0x102941c8c 0x102940778 0x10294de14 0x19e010bec 0x19e011744 0x19e599634 0x19e5996d4 0x19bff7a14 0x19b926614 0x19bed0ed0 0x19b926138 0x19ba99460 0x19ba99118 0x19b881d78 0x19b881510 0x19b880b88 0x19b862d84 0x19b862e98 0x19ac4f980 0x10378ab34 0x10379afec 0x10379aba0 0x19960901c 0x199605d28 0x199605478 0x1dcb864f8 0x19ba2962c 0x19ba28c68 0x19e4394b8 0x19e4392fc 0x19e0a9e90 0x10296f460 0x10296f610 0x1bc33edcc)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my class:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class CSVImporter
{
    public func importCSV(csvString: String) {
        let rows = csvString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        let dataController = DataController()
//        let context = dataController.container.viewContext
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
        
        for row in rows.dropFirst() {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            if columns.count == 6 {
                let amount = Float(columns[0])!
                var category = columns[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "Optional(\"", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: "\")", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
                let isEarning = Bool(columns[4])!
                let isMonthlyRecurring = Bool(columns[5])!
                
                
                dataController.addItem(amount: amount, category: category, isEarning: isEarning, isMonthlyRecurring: isMonthlyRecurring, context: managedObjContext)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this view I can save one data item without errors:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddBudgetView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var amount: Float = 0
    @State private var isEarning = false
    @State private var isMonthlyRecurring = false
    @FocusState private var isAmountFocused: Bool
    let emojis = ["", "️", "", "‍", "", "", "", ""]
    @State private var category = ""
    @Binding var showingAddDialogueFirstTime: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Add")) {
                    VStack {
                        Picker("Select an emoji", selection: $category) {
                                        ForEach(emojis, id: \.self) { emoji in
                                            Text(emoji)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .pickerStyle(.palette)
                                    Text("You selected \(category) category")
                        TextField("Amount", value: $amount, formatter: numberFormatter())
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($isAmountFocused)
                            .onAppear {
                                isAmountFocused = true
                            }
                        Toggle("Is earning", isOn: $isEarning)
                        Toggle("Monthly recurring", isOn: $isMonthlyRecurring)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button("Submit") {
                            DataController().addItem(
                                amount: amount,
                                category: category,
                                isEarning: isEarning,
                                isMonthlyRecurring: isMonthlyRecurring,
                                context: managedObjContext
                            )
                            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                            generator.impactOccurred()
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        if !showingAddDialogueFirstTime {
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                dismiss()
                            }
                        } else {
                            Button("Show listing") {
                                showingAddDialogueFirstTime = false
                                dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AddFoodView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @Binding var showingAddDialogueFirstTime: Bool
    static var previews: some View {
        AddBudgetView(showingAddDialogueFirstTime: Binding<Bool>.constant(false))
    }
}
```

For me it looks like the same approach with different results (see `DataController().addItem`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can't use `@Environment` outside of a `View` like that.

Comment: Somewhere you initialize your managedObjectContext environment object, use the same source where you got that object and use it to to inject a context into your CSVImporter class or to pass it into the import function